# Performing operations on a double returns 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, double

I have a method that receives a number in a NSString format.

I wish to convert this string to a double which I can use to calculate a temperature.

Here's my method.

```
NSString *stringTemp = text; // text is a NSString 
NSLog(@"%@",stringTemp); // used for debugging
double tempDouble = [stringTemp doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%f",tempDouble); // used for debugging
```

Please note I put the `NSLog` commands here just to see if the number was correct.  The latter `NSLog` returns a value of `82.000000` etc. (constantly changes as it's a temperature).

Next I wanted to use this `double` and convert it to a Celsius value.  To do so, I did this:

```
double celsiusTemp = (5 / 9) * (tempDouble - 32);
```

Doing this: `NSLog(@"%d", celsiusTemp);` , or this: `NSLog(@"%f", celsiusTemp);` both give me a value of 0 in the console.  Is there any reason why this would be happening?  Have I made a stupid mistake somewhere?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing (5.0 / 9.0). If you only use an int to do math where you are expecting a double to be returned (like 0.55) everything after the decimal place will be lost because the cpu expects an int to be returned.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks!  Forgive me for asking, but what is the placeholder value to get the answer merely to the tenth's place?

Comment: Heh, beat the masses by about 1 min. Think its safe to say thats probably your issue

Comment: It only works when you output the value to the UILabel or NSLog as it will always be stored in memory the way amount of bits that the type is (int / double), think its something like @"%.1f"

Comment: Just tested it, it was actually `%.1f`, but thanks again for your quick help, my friend!

Comment: Yeah just realised you meant 1 decimal place not 2. Vote up!

Answer (score 1):

`5 / 9` is the division of two integers, and as such uses integer division, which performs the division normally and then truncates the result. So the result of `5 / 9` is always the integer 0.

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't round?  It just takes the units place (which is 0).  I see!  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Right, it's exactly the same as if you cast the result to an int: (int)0.5555

Comment: Interesting! Well, now I know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
double celsiusTemp = (5.0 / 9) * (tempDouble - 32);
```

If you evaulate (5/9) as an integer, then it is just 0.